# Export MEF Part that comes from WCF service when composing a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, mef

I have an `WindowsService` application that uses `MEF` for object composition. The composition works OK (in the sense that all imports are satisfied and the app starts & runs with no errors) but I have the following problem: **one of the exported parts comes from a WCF service**. In order for this to work I make a synchronous call to the `WCF` service and get the instance. Then I use the result as a property export. I have something similar to the code below except that more objects in the hierarchy need this exported agent.

```
public class ExportedPrimitives{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ExportedPrimitives(IAgentService agentService)
    {
        //...
        try {
            agent = agentService.GetAgent();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            agent = new AgentModel();
        }
    }
    [Export("CurrentAgent")]
    public AgentModel Agent { get { return agent; } }
}

[Export]
public class Service:ServiceBase{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Service([Import("CurrentAgent")]AgentModel agent, ...other depencencies...){
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

As a result of this approach the service takes a long time to start and when deployed on slow machines the service times out. I know I'm not allowed to execute long running code in `Program.Main` or in the service `OnStart` method but I need that agent instance before the service can do its thing. I don't really want to modify the default service start timeout value. Also I don't think I can use `ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime` because I only use constructor injection. 
**My question is:** how can I improve the service start time? I'm sure I need to do an `async` call but I have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. If you came up with a solution, I would love to see it...